# Linux Mint: install subversion 1.7

Tags: linux, svn

On Linux Mint 17 with Subversion 1.8.x I have problem with committing files to SVN - I obtain **error**: "`svn: E120105: Error running context: The server sent an improper HTTP response`".
What works on another computer with older system version is subversion 1.7.x.

I tried many things to fix it (overview is here - http://jankoweb.moxo.cz/blog/open-source/svn-error-the-server-sent-an-improper-http-response-pri-commitu/) but nothing works for me.

Do you know how to fix this problem on Linux?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue is that the working copy format has been changed in svn 1.8.x, so you've two options I can think of:

1) run `svn upgrade` on the working copy. This may take a while depending on the size of the working copy, but it should sort things.

2) Check out a fresh working copy and use that, if you don't have too many changes to redo since the last checkout.

Hope that helps.

Comment: ad 1) does nothing for me - run immediately back to bash:( ad 2) I tried it, but does not work for me. I'm affraid, that problem is on svn server...

Comment: When you say it didn't work, do you mean the server wouldn't let you check out a new working copy? Did you get the same error?

Do you know what version of Subversion is running on the server?

Comment: I tried new working copy but when I tried commit, same error appears. Version of Subversion on server is unknown for my (by access throught web there is no footer with version:( ). But I think, that 1.7.x .